# Resetting flurry analytics in iOS

Tags: ios, flurry, flurry-analytics

How can I reset flurry analytics in iOS?

Comment: please put some codes, and if your question is about iOS, don't put irrelevant tag in your question.

Answer (score 4):

From Flurry analytics FAQ

> Is there a way to ignore "test" data or specific devices for analytics?
>
> Unfortunately we currently do not have a way to "reset" data at this time. You may want to try the following approach to prevent test data from appearing in your stats. Create two projects. One project for development/testing and one project for consumers. When you are ready to send the application to the public you can swap to the project key that points to the consumer project.
>
> Another alternative is to set the CUSTOM TIME FRAME in the analytics view of the application to the date the application is released on the Apple site. That way no previous data from testing/development will show in this time frame.
>
> This is another solution that some developers have used as well: Using Conditional Compilation to exclude the iPhone simulator runs from your stats

```
#ifdef DEBUG
[FlurryAPI startSession:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Go Admin(From Top) -> Apps(From Left)
See there are 2 small icons in center of each app, second one is delete icon.